# Рандомный SIGSEGV при вызове QSqlQuery::exec

Tags: sql, qt

Вызываю хранимую процедуру в MSSql, пробовал QDBC и QODBC3, может всю ночь прокрутить тысячи запросов, а может упасть сразу же на первом или втором, но обычно до 500 запросов осиливает.

```
================= Стэк вызовов =================
       1   QVarLengthArray<wchar_t, 256>::append   qvarlengtharray.h       350  0x678ce8a8 
       2   QODBCResult::exec                       qsql_odbc.cpp           1726 0x678cbcfc 
       3   QSqlQuery::exec                         qsqlquery.cpp           1012 0x67b41df9 
**-->**4   network::check_ticket                   main_server.h           216  0x4069eb   
       5   network::parser                         main_server.h           478  0x40a7af   
       6   network::slot_wicket_readyRead          main_server.h           409  0x409126   
       7   network::qt_static_metacall             moc_main_server.cpp     128  0x4016fe   
       8   QMetaObject::activate                   qobject.cpp             3793 0x6bb1f72e 
       9   QMetaObject::activate                   qobject.cpp             3646 0x6bb1f9bd 
       10  QIODevice::readyRead                    moc_qiodevice.cpp       189  0x6ba635b3 
       11  QAbstractSocketPrivate::emitReadyRead   qabstractsocket.cpp     1307 0x126e94d
```

Соединение с БД с помощью приватных переменных класса.
Сначала вызываю

```
void create_db_connect(QString db_name, int db_port, QString db_user, QString db_pass)
    {
        db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC3");
        db.setDatabaseName( "DRIVER={SQL Server}; Server=" + database_addr_server + "; Database=" + db_name + ";CharSet=UTF16; Trusted_Connection=no; " );
        db.setUserName(db_user);
        db.setPassword(db_pass);
        db.setHostName(database_addr_server);
        db.setPort(db_port);
        db.setConnectOptions("SQL_ATTR_ACCESS_MODE=SQL_MODE_READ_WRITE;SQL_ATTR_CONNECTION_POOLING=SQL_CP_ONE_PER_HENV;SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION=SQL_OV_ODBC4;SQL_ATTR_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT=20;SQL_ATTR_LOGIN_TIMEOUT=20;");
    }
```

Потом

```
bool db_open(QString target_error)
    {
        if ( !db.open() )
        {
            logger(target_error + " last error - " + db.lastError().text() );
            return false;
        }
        //logger(target_error + " db open:");
        check_ticket_query = new QSqlQuery(db);
        confirm_pass_query = new QSqlQuery(db);
        check_ticket_query->prepare("{ call dbo.usp__CheckTicketFromGate( :x , :result , :desc ) }");
                confirm_pass_query->prepare("{ call dbo.usp__ConfirmPass_light( :x , :result , :desc ) }");
        return true;
    }
```

Ну и вызываю так:

```
QString xml = "Тут хмл на вход процедуры";
        check_ticket_query->bindValue(":x", xml, QSql::In );
        check_ticket_query->bindValue(":result", result, QSql::Out);
        check_ticket_query->bindValue(":desc", desc, QSql::Out);
        Q_CHECK_PTR(check_ticket_query);
**-->** if (!check_ticket_query->exec())
            logger("check_ticket last error - " + check_ticket_query->lastError().text() );

        result = check_ticket_query->boundValue(":result").toByteArray();
        desc = check_ticket_query->boundValue(":desc").toByteArray();
```

И вот на query.exec может рандомно падать.
Вдобавок есть интересная магия, для того что бы получить ответные строки нужно строки в которые будет вывод подготовить, заполнив их любыми символами,

```
QString result(49, ' ');
QString desc(127, 'x')
```

иначе они возвращаются пустыми, при этом в процедуре они определены так

```
@result nvarchar(50) output,
@desc nvarchar(128) output
```

если сделать заполнение меньше, например

```
QString desc(20, ' ');
```

то все будет работать, а если больше

```
QString desc(128, ' ');
```

то будет ошибка драйвера

> QODBCResult::exec: Unable to execute statement:  "[Microsoft][ODBC SQL
> Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid parameter 9 (''): Data type 0x63 is
> a deprecated large object, or LOB, but is marked as output parameter.
> Deprecated types are not supported as output parameters. Use current
> large object types instead. "check_ticket last error -
> [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid parameter 9
> (''): Data type 0x63 is a deprecated large object, or LOB, but is
> marked as output parameter. Deprecated types are not supported as
> output parameters. Use current large object types instead. QODBC3:
> Unable to execute statement

Так же хотелось бы знать что это за магическое ограничение в 127 символов в строке и связано ли оно с падением на выполнении запроса?

Исполняю в одном потоке, без гуя в консоли.

UPD: Исправил функцию

```
bool db_open(QString target_error)
    {
       if ( !db.isOpen() )
            if ( !db.open() )
                return false;
            return true;
    }
```

Иначе я просто всегда пытался открыть базу..
Также исправил создание запроса, теперь он создается там же где и выполняется

```
QSqlQuery check_ticket_query( db );                        //новый запрос
QString xml = "Тут хмл на вход процедуры";
        check_ticket_query->bindValue(":x", xml, QSql::In );
        check_ticket_query->bindValue(":result", result, QSql::Out);
        check_ticket_query->bindValue(":desc", desc, QSql::Out);
**-->** if (!check_ticket_query->exec())
            logger("check_ticket last error - " + check_ticket_query->lastError().text() );

        result = check_ticket_query->boundValue(":result").toByteArray();
        desc = check_ticket_query->boundValue(":desc").toByteArray();
```

Без изменений, все так же падаем на методе `QVarLegthArray::append`

Comment: xml проверяется на валидность перед отправлением в процедуру? Есть лог параметров, при которых падает прога?

Comment: xml валиден, я запускаю например в отладке и при падении смотрю значения переменных. Какой именно лог нужен? Процедура работает при любом хмл на входе, вернее ничего не делает если на вход белиберда или пустота.

Comment: Тяжело сказать в чем причина падения приложения. Код, который вы выложили правильный, а ошибка говорит о "нелегальном" доступе к памяти. Вот я и подумал, что в какой-то момент у вас появляется какой-то не такой xml. Может быть слишком большой, или вообще пустой - вы же видите какой капризный драйвер )

Comment: `<gateIP>10.1.7.232</gateIP><direction>In</direction><barcode>9780201379624</barcode>` сейчас всегда такой прилетает, может упасть, а может не упасть. Думаю это связано с ограничением на длину строки. А вообще существует описание протокола связи с БД? Мне уже кажется проще реализовать свой драйвер..

Comment: Что значит прилетает? Из сети асинхронно? А в таком случае, не перетирается ли ваш xml в какой-то момент передачи в БД?

Comment: нет, исключено,запрос обрабатывается синхронно, ну и сейчас реализован тестовый механизм, который раз в секунду дергает функцию, когда она падает я в дизигнере вижу кадр с переменными, и там всегда неизменная строка

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100746/discussion-between-alexander-chernin-and-dow-jhob).

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что aaaa